# App crashing on checking count NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift3, nsmutablearray

the app crashes on checking for count of NSMutablearray if it is nil,i am not getting how to handle it, i am new to ios

```
let userDefaults: UserDefaults? = UserDefaults.standard
    let array  = userDefaults?.object(forKey: "purchaselist") as? NSMutableArray
    for i in 0..<array!.count {
}
```

Comment: Apart from the issue 1) `UserDefaults.standard` is never `nil`, your type annotation makes it worse, and 2) Conditional downcast to `NSMutableArray` never works (the object is immutable or `nil`), and 3) There is an API `array(forKey` in `UserDefaults`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for nil also,

```
if let array = userDefaults?.object(forKey: "purchaselist") as? [Any], !array.isEmpty {
    //Your code goes here
}
```

You can do this way also,

```
if let array = userDefaults?.object(forKey: "purchaselist") as? NSMutableArray {
    if array.count != 0 {
        //Your code goes here
    } else {
        //array count zero 
    }
} else {
    //Your array is nil
}
```

FYI. Code is not tested, it is just information.

Comment: yeah you have to do this